# Is there anything similar to R data.table in python?

Tags: python, r, data.table

I am a R user. I am trying to "translate" my R habit to python. Is there anything similar to R data.table in python?

Comment: Maybe this could help https://datascience-enthusiast.com/R/pandas_datatable.html

Comment: Personally I love `data.table`. I suspect the answers given are sufficient but this question might be improved if you were able to clarify what you were seeking to replicate. Is it just working with data in a tabular form? Is it the syntax? Is it the speed/performance?

Comment: Today there is. I suggest you try Polars.

Answer (score 1):

yes,  datatable for python : [python datatable](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/v0.10.1/)

- [the github link](https://github.com/h2oai/datatable)
- [An Overview of Python’s Datatable package](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-overview-of-pythons-datatable-package-5d3a97394ee9)

form [github page](https://github.com/h2oai/datatable):
'**As the name suggests, the package is closely related to R's data.table and attempts to mimic its core algorithms and API.**'

You can also use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

[datatable](https://pypi.org/project/datatable/) from pypy

*"Python library for fast multi-threaded data manipulation and munging."*

**or the more well-known and widely used:**

[pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/), also from pypy

*"Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics"*

Both are solid options

Comment: I tried to install datatable in python, however, it is still not available on windows. I used pandas as well, but the syntex is sometime tedious in compare to data.table in R(for example for filtering and selecting). I think I have to use pandas, even though its syntex is sometimes tedious.

Comment: you can try for windows (https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/v0.10.1/install.html), from me, i use windows, i think i download the package first (https://pypi.org/project/datatable/#files),  and then install from local .whl .  @QiYin

Answer (score -1):

Sound like you're looking for something like a [Pandas Dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)?

Something like

```
import pandas as pd

dict_data = {"Col A": [1, 2], "Col B": [3, 4]}
df = pd.Dataframe(data=dict_data)
print(df)
```

would produce the output

```
   Col A  Col B
 0 1      3
 1 2      4
```